# Make element dividing lines equal height with container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navigation, navbar

I'm trying to do a simple navbar, but the size of the border matches the size of the text and not its container's height. I'm trying to 'close' each text inside its own 'rectangle'. How do I achieve that?

```css
.flex-r {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    justify-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    gap: 1em;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-height: 40px;
}

.nav-item {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
 <div class='flex-r'><a class='nav-item'>Release</a><a class='nav-item'>Statistics</a><a class='nav-item'>Frequent releases</a></div>
```

Comment: Could you please specify your question? What do you mean with "the size of the border" and what do you mean with " 'close' each text inside its own 'rectangle' "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the container set to `min-height: 40px`.

Add the same code to the items.

But here's a better overall solution that may work for you:

```css
.flex-r {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 1px;                /* sets the dividing line width */
  background-color: black; /* sets the dividing line color */
  border: 1px solid black; /* sets the border around the container */
  min-height: 40px;
}

.nav-item {
  background-color: white; /* restores background color */
  
  /* center the content */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-r'>
   <a class='nav-item'>Release</a>
   <a class='nav-item'>Statistics</a>
   <a class='nav-item'>Frequent releases</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the edit and the solution. It works but what you suggested in the first line, I also have tried it before and it makes the text goes to the top of the div, which I don't want.

Comment: For that problem (in your original code), use the `flex` centering solution I provided.